# Turn .../?token=xx-xxx into .../xx-xxx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a htaccess-file that removes index.php (codeigniter). I am having a problem with Paypal, cause the return url is using query strings, which are troublesome in codeigniter.

This is my htaccess-file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want to rewrite the following example url-s:

```
http://.../site/bookingconfirmed/?token=EC-56G61173NH540131H
```

to

```
http://.../site/bookingconfirmed/EC-56G61173NH540131H
```

and

```
http://.../site/bookingdeclined/?token=EC-56G61173NH540131H
```

to

```
http//.../site/bookingdeclined/EC-56G61173NH540131H
```

Any good ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add these rules right below `RewriteBase /`

```
#for booking confirmed and declined
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /site/booking(confirmed|declined)/$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)token=([^&]+)(&|$) [NC]
#rewrite to /site/bookingdeclined/EC-56G61173NH540131H
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}%2 [L]
```

If you want to change the URL that the client sees in their address bar change the last rule to

```
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}%2 [L,R=301]
```